# Angular router shows the relevant url in browser'url bar, but the content of that url is not displayed in browser page

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm having an issue with the angular router and I think it is pretty much because I'm new to it. This is my scenario.
Inside my authModule I have a login page, from which after login success should redirect the user to the Dashboard page which also has 3 children components namely Home, statitics, parameters and notifications. So I end up with this components tree:

```
AuthModule
    _LoginComponent
      _DashboardComponent
        _HomeComponent
        _StatisticsComponent
        _ParametersComponent
        _NotificationsComponent
  SharedModule
```

I defined the routes in the authModule like this:

```
const routes = [
  {path:'', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch:'full'},
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashbaordComponent,
        children: [
          {path:'', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch:'full'},
          {path:'home', component:HomeComponent},
          {path:'statistics', component:StatisticsComponent},
          {path:'parameters', component:ParametersComponent},
          {path:'notifications', component:NotificationsComponent},
        ]
    }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I redirect to the dashboard after login success from the loginEffect class:

```
tap(() => (request.user.response == 'ok') ? this.router.navigate(['login/dashboard']) : this.router.navigate(['login']) )
```

Unfortunately after login action is successfull the url changes to 'login/dashboard' but the dashboard content is not shown. So I tried to put the **outlet** at the bottom of the login template like this `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, and with that the dashboard is displayed beneath the login page which should normally have disappeared but reamains. I think that I shouldn't use the outlet since the dashboard's template is independant from the login's template, and shares nothing with the login template. Only the home, staistics, parameters and notifications share a portion of the dashboard. How can I then make do with this case. I appreaciate your help. If you need further information, please let me know in comment.

**UPDATE**: (For clarification)
I just want to clarify that the redirection was working fine when I didn't nest the dashboad component inside that of login. This is the component tree I had when the routing and the redirection were going fine:

```
AuthModule
  _LoginComponent (independant path)
  _DashboardComponent (independant path)
     _HomeComponent (nested paths to dashboard)
     _StatisticsComponent (nested paths to dashboard)
     _ParametersComponent (nested paths to dashboard)
     _NotificationsComponent (nested paths to dashboard)
SharedModule
```

Here dashboard component was not nested inside login, and it was working fine. the reason why I had to change this late components tree to the first I gave in the beginning is to prevent user from getting to dashboard without login, because with this last components tree, user can get to login/dashboard without login.
This clarifications are because I can't easily produce a stackblitz for this case.

> THE TEMPLATES:

**login.component.html**

```
<div class="third-box">
        <div class="sign-in-from">
            <h1 class="mb-0 title">Connexion</h1>
            <form class="mt-4" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>EMAIL</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control mb-0"  placeholder="Your identifier" formControlName="username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>HI CODE</label>
                  <input class="form-control mb-0"  placeholder="Your HI CODE" formControlName="X_HI_CODE">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">PASSWORD</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control mb-0" formControlName="password" placeholder="Your password" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">Connexion</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<mat-drawer-container>
  <mat-drawer mode="side" [opened]="firstSideBarOpen">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  </mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content>
    <app-header (toggleSidebarForMe)="FirstSideBarToggler()"></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

The home.component.html, statistics.component.html, parameter.component.html and notification.component.html are only html without outlet

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will be helpful if you share some your working problem code. Thanks!

Comment: @Vivek What is working problem code ?

Comment: while your description is helpful, the code snippets are not enough. Maybe a stackblitz link will be helpful to see what you are facing

Comment: Add your html code to the question, cause it sounds like you have two `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, one that renders `LoginComponent`, and the other one you have inside `LoginComponent`

Comment: @onrails I used ngrx store, ngrx effect, ngrx entity for this part of the project and it will be just like more difficult to make a stackblitf of it. But I updated my post for clarification

Comment: @Nehal Yeah I used the <router-outlet></router-outlet> only in the dashboard template to display it nested children. But out of confusion about how the dashboard is not displayed after login, I added another <router-outlet></router-outlet> at the bottom of the login template also, but that was a silly idea because in so doing the dashboard is now displayed but at the bottom of the login page, which is not what I want. What I want is routing for login page to dashboard, and not having the dashboard to be sharing some spaces with login page.

Comment: You still haven't added your html code in the question. And why are dashboard routes children of login route? It seems like you have something configured totally wrong in your codebase, and SO users can't help you w/o full view of your code. Your best chance to get help is to put your exact code the question, or create a stackblitz

Comment: @Nehal I added the templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, the snippets you provided are insufficient.

On another note, I don't think that the hierarchy of your routes makes any sense. Why would you want to display the `login` part after your user is logged in?

See [this StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-router-outlet-with-menu) which I think does what you are looking for.

**EDIT:**

Well, you must be using something in your `State` to determine that the user is logged in. For simplicity, let's assume that you have a boolean `isAuthenticated` in a slice of your state:

```
export interface AuthState {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
}
```

Your `loginEffect` should dispatch a `loginSuccess` action, if the backend determined the user credentials are correct. The reducer handling the `loginSuccess` can set the `isAuthenticated` to `true`.
Then, in your reducer file, you can create a selector and then subscribe to this selector like this:

```
isLoggedIn$;
constructor(store: Store) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.store(select(selectIsAuthenticated));
}
```

See [new StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-router-outlet-with-menu-ngrx).

Comment: Thanks,  but in my case authentication, authorization and redirection are made in the loginEffect like  login$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(ofType(loginAction)). I don't know how to make this.isLoggedInSubject.next(true) in the situation where one uses ngrx effect to complete the login process and dispatch some important value to the store. I mean if I do this.isLoggedInSubject.next(true) in loginEffect, how can I then get the value this.isLoggedIn$ = authService.isLoggedIn$.pipe() in the dashboard since authService doesn't have the last change of this.isLoggedIn$ by loginEffect.

Comment: @Prenam I've edited my answer to cover your case.

Comment: Yeah this  seems to be the answer for me, but redirection to dashboard seems to be requested before loginsuccess's action get a chance to set isAuthenticated to true. So isAuthenticated seems to be false in the dashboard component where I did (this.isAuthenticated) ? router.navigate(['dashboard']) : router.navigate(['login']). Please take a look at how I implement my loginEffect in next comment

Comment: login$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(loginAction), 
        switchMap(({request}) => {
          return this.authService.login(request)
         .pipe(
                map((currentUser: CurrrentUserInterface) => {
                   console.log('current user', currentUser); 
                   this.roleIds == currentUser.result.roleIds; 
                   return loginSuccessAction({currentUser}) 
               }),
               tap(() => (request.user.username == 'hi-admin') ? this.router.navigate(['dashboard']) : this.router.navigate(['login']) ),

Comment: Even though it's not solved yet I know this is the track. Again thank you in advance

Comment: @Prenam I have included a new StackBlitz demo.